# Image not loading with picasso or Glide.. keeps displaying blank image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, picasso

I'm trying to load an image from firebase real time database using picasso, but it keeps displaying blank image... I got the same result when I tried using Glide.
I tried to use this solution : [[Image not loading with picasso or glide..keeps displaying black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293600/image-not-loading-with-picasso-or-glide-keeps-displaying-black-background][1]) But it doesn't work for me

Here's the code :

ProfileInfoActivity

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ProfileInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
    private TextView mName;
    private EditText mEditName, mEmail;

    private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

    private StorageReference mImageStorage;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_info);

        mDisplayImage = findViewById(R.id.circle_image);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        mEditName = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email_address);

        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String userID = mCurrentUser.getUid();

        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String et_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String et_email_adress = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                mName.setText(name);
                mEditName.setText(et_name);
                mEmail.setText(et_email_adress);

                Picasso.get().load(image).into(mDisplayImage);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mDisplayImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICK);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);

            //Toast.makeText(ProfileInfoActivity.this, imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileInfoActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Image...");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we upload and process the image");
                mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();


                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

                StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");

                filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            String download_url = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            mDatabaseReference.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                    }

                                }
                            });


                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(ProfileInfoActivity.this, "Error in uploading: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    }
                });

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ProfileInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".login.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".login.SignupActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/setting"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/> <!-- optional (needed if default theme has no action bar) -->

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that when I upload an image from device, download url is getting as com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@6534db7. So, all details were uploaded into realtime database correctly except image url.

**Solution :**

Declare filepath as final, and use onSuccess Listener instead of onComplete Listener and change the download url from task.getResult simply to uri.toString();

```
filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String download_url = uri.toString();
                                mDatabaseReference.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileInfoActivity.this,"Success Uploading",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Another tip if in the future you get problems loading images, all images should start with https:// if you use Glide, if you try to load an image with http it wont load

Comment: this maybe is not duplicate, sometimes it works to uninstall the app and run it again in case you have socket connection error. (check logcat)